# How to normalize or design my MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to know which one structure is good to store about 50 data in same time into MySQL?

First

```
 data_id  user_id      data_key    data_content
 ---------------------------------------------------
 1        2            data_key1   content 1
 2        2            data_key2   content 2
 3        2            data_key3   content 3
 ..       ..           ..          ..
 ..       ..           ..          ..
 50       2            data_key50  content 50
```

Seconds

```
 data_id  user_id  data_key1  data_key2  data_key3  .. ..  data_key50
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
 1        2        content 1  content 2  content 3  .. ..  content 50
```

Or have other solution? `user_id` will have more than 5000 users.

Comment: In the second case, why do you have a data_id column? If you already have 50 columns, there's no need for fifty rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the data keys before hand and are they likely to change? If they're along the lines of "first_name, last_name, hair_color, eye_color, birthday, ..." then the second model would be feasible since you'll often want to retrieve all of these for a user at the same time.

The first model is like having a persistent hashtable, so you'd have to store all the values as strings, and your app will have to know which keys to query for. This can make sense if the keys are user defined, however.

Comment: All the `data_key` fixed and `data_content` by user.

Comment: Then I would go with the second approach, just don't call the columns data_key1, data_key2, give them meaningful names. If you can segment them according to how you'll be retrieving them, that could be an optimization (e.g. if you have 10 columns about a user's interests and 10 about a user's appearance, then you may want to have user 1<->1 interest, and user 1<->1 appearance  (separate tables for the interes columns and the appearance columns)

Comment: Yes the column will be meaningful names. Thanks for the suggestion Ben.

Comment: or better separate the `data_key` to another table? example `profile_table` will have `data_key1 till data_key10`, `education_table` with `data_key11 till data_key20`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the first one! What if the need arises to have more than 50 different "data keys". The first solution is way more flexible and unpolluted.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the second solution is a goeod one.
If I do not suppose wrong not all tue users are 2, but you have different numbers what you should do is normalize that table, divide it in to.

One that has:

Table main:
id , data_id, user_id

Table key
main_id, data_key

Table data:
main_id,data_content

where in both tables key and data main_id reffer to the id in the table main, which is the way to join them